# When PropertyChanged called event PropertyChanged=null

Tags: wpf, binding, treeview, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class derived from INotifyPropertyChanged to track property changes. This properties are bound to a TreeView and are needed to perform searching in TreeViewItems. When in properties setters `this.OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded")` is called for some reason `this.PropertyChanged == null` when "IsExpanded" bubbled to the root element of the TreeView. Why is it null here and not null on deeper TreeView elements? What can I to solve this issue?
My code cs:

```
    public class TreeViewItemViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    ....................

        bool _isExpanded;
        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get { return _isExpanded; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _isExpanded)
                {
                    _isExpanded = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
                }

                //Expand all till the root
                if (_isExpanded && _parent != null)
                    _parent._isExpanded = true;

                //Lazy load children, if nessesary
                if (this.HasDummyChild)
                {
                    this.Children.Remove(DummyChild);
                    this.LoadChildren();
                }
            }

        }

        bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _isSelected)
                {
                    _isSelected = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                }
            }
        }
    .............................
    }
```

My code XAML:

```
          <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Areas}">
                <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                      DataType="{x:Type vAreas:AreaViewModel}" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
                      >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.Resources>
            </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I never subscribe for my event PropertyChanged.
As soon as I subscribe for it  it start to work fine

```
this.PropertyChanged += AreaViewModel_PropertyChanged;
```

---

```
void AreaViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "IsExpanded")
        {
            //Expand all till the root
            if (this.IsExpanded && this.Parent != null)
                this.Parent.IsExpanded = true;

            //Lazy load children, if nessesary
            if (this.HasDummyChild)
            {
                this.Children.Remove(DummyChild);
                this.LoadChildren();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this one for a while. In the end it turned out that my collection feeding the treeview was an ObservableCollection property, but was actually a list.

As soon as I turned it into an ObservableCollection everything started working.